# LINQ to Entities and MaxBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, maxby

I want to try to use `MaxBy` for type `DateTime`

My model is:

```
public class DownloadCenterFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string FolderName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DownloadCenterFile> DownloadCenterFiles { get; protected set; } = new List<DownloadCenterFile>();
}

public class DownloadCenterFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string FileNameFriendly { get; set; }
    public required string FileNameUnique { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateLastUpdated { get; set; }
    public long ContentLenght { get; set; }

    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual DownloadCenterFolder DownloadCenterFolder { get; set; }
}
```

and DTO class:

```
public class DownloadCenterFolderElementDto
{
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateLastUpdated { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

and automapper rule:

```
    CreateMap<DownloadCenterFolder, DownloadCenterFolderElementDto>()
        .ForMember(d => d.FolderID, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.Size, o => o.MapFrom(i => (i.DownloadCenterFiles.Count() > 0) ? i.DownloadCenterFiles.Sum(p => p.ContentLenght) : 0))
        .ForMember(d => d.DateLastUpdated, o => o.MapFrom(i => (i.DownloadCenterFiles.Count() > 0) ? i.DownloadCenterFiles.MaxBy(p => p.DateAdded).DateAdded : (DateTime?)null))
        ;
```

and call:

```
    var list = await _db.DownloadCenterFolders.ProjectTo<DownloadCenterFolderElementDto>(_mapperConfig).ToListAsync();
```

Unit Tests says ok, but real call to SQL throws an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'MaterializeCollectionNavigation( Navigation:
> DownloadCenterFolder.DownloadCenterFiles, subquery:
> DbSet() .Where(d1 => EF.Property<int?>(d, "Id") !=
> null && object.Equals( objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(d, "Id"), objB:
> (object)EF.Property<int?>(d1, "FolderId"))) .Where(i =>
> EF.Property<int?>(d, "Id") != null && object.Equals( objA:
> (object)EF.Property<int?>(d, "Id"), objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(i,
> "FolderId")))) .AsQueryable() .MaxBy(p => p.DateAdded)' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

if I change `MaxBy` query to :

```
.ForMember(d => d.DateLastUpdated, o => o.MapFrom(i => (i.DownloadCenterFiles.Count() > 0) ? i.DownloadCenterFiles.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateAdded).Select(p => p.DateAdded).FirstOrDefault() : (DateTime?)null))
```

it works fine. I thought, `MaxBy` is equivalent of `OrderByDescending(..).FirstOrDefault()` but now is a little confused. How so and how to use it correctly?

Comment: You can't use method which is not supported (does not have translation implementation). This is what exception message is telling you: "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or ...". I guess you know that any new method added to `IQueryable` does not get automatic implementation as for `IEnumerable`. All recently added `*By` methods by BCL team are not yet implemented in EF (8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the fact that some LINQ query works fine in LINQ-to-Objects, doesn't mean it will also work fine in EFCore. Additionally, the fact that one operator might be "equivalent" to a sequence of other operators that are known to work, also doesn't mean the "composite" operator will work, as they are analyzed in isolation to one another.

The way EFCore works is by taking the `IQueryable`'s abstract syntax tree and trying to see which pieces match which SQL statements. It sees a "`MaxBy`" call in the tree and currently doesn't know how to convert that to SQL. Not all LINQ operators are supported, and some will throw the exception you saw there.

Support for `MinBy`/`MaxBy` hasn't been implemented yet as you can see from this issue:

- [Support SQL translation for .Net 6 Linq's MinBy/MaxBy Methods #25566](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25566)

Comment: hmm, almost 3 years of the problem and it's not implemented for EF Core....

Comment: @OlegSh yeah its a bit frustrating... the backlog on some of those teams is just not compatible with how many resources are allocated to them. EFCore has been catching up for several years now and only recently finally managed to get parity with legacy EF. Other Microsoft teams are in similar or even worse situations, unfortunately.